# Add two root users during installation during installation + managing it - Ubuntu server

Tags: server, root, virtualization, administration

I would like to ask you all, that is it possible to enter some kind of script before entering the setup screen to be able to add 2 root users instantly.
I am at the beginning of creating 190 virtual machines where I need to add 2 root users (on for students, and one for the teachers). Is there some kind of method to manage all these virtual machines (the operating system) to see all the directories and etc.?

Thank you very much.

Cheers,
Csaba

Answer (score 0):

script for adding 2 user with root privilege:

```
useradd student 
useradd teacher

echo "student ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
echo "teacher ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

but you will need to run this script on each linux vm. :(

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is this script appliable during the installation, or do I need to put it somewhere else?
What about the separate virtual machine, where the teachers can check the folders? Is it the second line where you have written ALL:ALL?

Thanks